# Where is electrostatic potential energy stored in a capacitor system?

Tags: capacitor, energy

We know,

$$U = \frac{ \epsilon_o}{2} \int_{\partial S} |E|^2 \mathrm{dV}$$

Now, suppose you have a capacitor system of the geometry as shown below,

[image]

I know energy is stored between plates of a capacitor, however I have recently came across questions related to an exam which I'm writing where I have to find the region which contains half the energy. For example one of the questions I encountered was being given a cylindrical capacitor, when the capacitor is fully charged, where the region of radius 'r' where half of the potential energy lies?

So, for this question I was confused because there could be many such cylindrical volumes which contains half of capacitors energies. The answer to questions involves finding the cylindrical volume having axis as axis of cylinder, but, how would one proof this is the only such cylindrical volume which contains half the energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking something very fundamental. The stored energy is a property of the whole system - the charged capacitor. I mean the metal, the insulation and the caused state change, the unnatural imbalance caused by charging. Of course it's possible to create a totally artificial border. We search the area between the plates where the electric field is substantially stronger than it was when the capacitor was not charged and say: "It's here".

But that's not the truth for everyone because that field gives to the electrons a possibility to drop and do some work. As well we could say "it's in electrons which are accumulated in the unbalanced way, we only calculate the amount of available work with the field".

In physics we have learned to keep the field existent, it's not only a handy concept to make calculations. But we still do not know what the field actually is. It's easy to us to understand that the invisible air around us is a bunch of randomly moving gas molecules, but we cannot say what the field is made of.

I would say it's just the field and it holds the energy that can be released by discharging the capacitor. It's a property of the space to have such state as electric field.

The energy in a cylindrical capacitor:

I guess you can think the capacitor as 2 concentric cylindrical capacitors in series - the inner one and the outer one. Imagine one cylindrical equipotential surface between the plates. Somewhere is the exact place for the border so that the inner capacitor has as much energy as the outer capacitor.

But if you think there's  2 intermediate cylindrical equipotential surfaces so that the capacitor is total three concentric capacitors in series there's infinitely possibilities to place the 2 intermediate surfaces so that the imagined capacitor between them contains half of the total stored energy.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be a "volume" thing based on the wording of the question.   In parallel plate capacitor, you can easily find the '1/2 energy' point just by thinking about it.  It'll be midway between the plates.   So half the volume on either side.

In a cylinder, that point won't be 1/2 way between the 'plates'.  It'll be much closer to the outside shell.   You'll have to do some math to figure out where.  (geometry and/or calculus, not circuit analysis).  There will be some gradient in the 'energy per unit volume', which is where the calculus comes in.

Comment: My main question is, wouldn't there be many such surfaces whose volumes contain "half the energy" ?

Comment: I think there would be one single surface for any given R1 and R2.   And you probably have to put your answer in that form (as an equation).

Comment: I bet this will help:    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieK0g58PTjo

Comment: How can you prove there is only one surface? I'm having hard time bealiving that there is only one surface

Comment: Suppose you have a spherical balloon(imaginaryone), which I can stretch and expand, and I through some glitter in the air, now if I wanted to get half the glitter I threw up, I am 100000% sure I could stretch and squish the balloon to find more than one surface which contains half the glitter

Comment: @DDD4C4U   Do you accept that the "1/2 energy" point of a parallel plate capacitor is at the mid-point between the two plates?  If so, then why is it be unreasonable to assume a similar point exists between two concentric cylinders?     True, if you 'stretch and squish" things, you can find many points of "1/2 energy".   With the parallel plate example, you could cut the plates in half lengthwise, and get left & right areas (instead of top & bottom) that contain "1/2 energy".  I propose you are over-thinking the intent of the question.  Perhaps the question should say "symmetrical surfaces".

Comment: Why do you say points? I think it should be volumes. But, if you think my understanding of  intent is wrong, then what was correct  understanding of intent?

Comment: From your balloon example - if you allow asymmetrical surfaces to be considered, then there are infinitely many ways to divide the volumes such that they contain equal energy.   That makes the question of " find the region which contains half the energy" irrelevant and nonsensical.  So one must wonder, what is the actual intent of the question?  Is it a trick question or is it intended to actually be answered.  If it's a trick question, then your interpretation is correct and the answer is "infinity".  If it's meant to be answered, then only symmetrical surfaces would yield a singular answer.

Comment: It's like if you ask somebody to cut a napkin in half.   Most people would assume you meant "down the middle".  Some people would cut corner to corner.  Although you could achieve it by cutting spirals and other non-symmetrical lines.